# Realm: Cannot invoke 'objects' with an argument list of type '(Object.Type)'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

So I have a very simple Book model in Realm

```
class Book: Object {

    dynamic var title: String!
    dynamic var author: String!
}
```

And I'm trying to retrieve all of my books in a helper class:

```
var userBookLibrary = [Book]()
let realm = try! Realm()    

func getBooksFromLocalDatastore() {
    userBookLibrary = realm.objects(Book)
}
```

This line:

```
userBookLibrary = realm.objects(Book)
```

throws the error in the title.

Have I gone mad or is this not ***exactly*** what the Realm documentation tells us to do ?

Comment: How and where do you define `userBookLibrary` and `realm`?

Comment: @joern sry for that, updated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`realm.objects()` does not return `[Book]` but `Results<Book>?`. So you have to change the type of `userBookLibrary`:

```
var userBookLibrary = Results<Book>?
```